# iPad UI clipped in simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

My views created for iPad form factor look fine in Interface Builder. However, when I debug my app in iPhone Simulator 3.2 (with Hardware -> Device set to iPad), I see the UI clipped and about half size. There is a **2x** button at the bottom which lets me zoom in. But this just shows the same clipped UI in double size.

This is really weird since I have created the XIB for iPad form factor and it is supposed to fit iPad completely. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

I am using iPhone SDK 3.2 downloaded on 4/30/2010.

Thanks.

-Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've accidentally created an iphone project, rather than an ipad project.  In the "New Project Dialog", make sure you select iPad from the "Product" dropdown in the middle of the dialog:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7f49d44254.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7f49d44254.png)

Comment: Scotty, Thanks for the quick answer. Is there a way to change this after the project is already created?

Comment: Figured it out. Project ->Edit Active Target -> Build -> Deployment ->Targeted Device Family.